# store variable in variable

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a problem about store variable in variable, but I really don't know if it's possible or not.

```
$uType = 1;

if ($uType == 1){
    $pageType = " Country <select name='country$i' id='country$i'><option selected disabled>Choose Country</option></select>";
}else{
do something
}

$num = 2;

for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
            print "
            <tr>
                <td>Link/URL $i</td>
                <td><input type='text' class='textinput1'  size='70' name='url$i' id='url$i' value='http://' />".$pageType."</td>
            </tr>";
            }
```

I want to print country option with dynamic `id` and `name` tag, but it doesn't work, or it's possible or not? Using `$$i` or `\$i` doesn't work, either.

There is no error message, but country option name and id tag aren't dynamic, only show

```
<select name="country" ...
```

I want to make it dynamic:

```
<select name="country1" ...
```

Sorry for bad description, i think you guys understand what i think when look at code, thank you.

Comment: When you say "it's don't work" what happen ? Please, type the error message.

Comment: no error message, but country option name and id tag not dynamic, only show _ <select name="country".._ i want to make it dynamic, _<select name="country1" .._ etc

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this actually. You can choose from following examples

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    printf("
        <tr>
          <td>Link/URL %1$s</td>
          <td>
            <input size='70' name='url%1$s' id='url%1$s' />%2$s
          </td>
        </tr>
    ", $i, $pageType);
}
```

Or even something as simple as this should work

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "
        <tr>
          <td>Link/URL $i</td>
          <td>
           <input size='70' name='url$i' id='url$i' />$pageType
          </td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should describe better what error you are getting.

Anyway, what i see is you are using a `$i` variable in the `if` sentence, and it wasn't declarated before.

On the other hand, try putting the variables into `{}` characters, it may help PHP to know that it is a variable.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
    print "
        <tr>
           <td>Link/URL {$i}</td>
           <td><input type='text' class='textinput1'  size='70' name='url{$i}' id='url{$i}' value='http://' />".$pageType."</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understande your question, you want to place the $i variable in $pageType with it actual value in for loop.

This could work for you, change the $pageType variable to something like

```
$pageType = 'Country <select name="country%1$s " id="country%1$s"><option selected disabled>Choose Country</option></select>';
```

note the %1$s placeholder here and the double quotes changed to single quotes and vice versa.

Then whenever you need to render the $pageType variable with dynamic id, use the php function [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), in your case it will be :

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
            print "
            <tr>
                <td>Link/URL $i</td>
                <td><input type='text' class='textinput1'  size='70' name='url$i' id='url$i' value='http://' />". sprintf($pageType, $i) ."</td>
            </tr>";
            }
```

Hope this wil help